# Evaluation of Element?

Tags: numerics, core-language

What is the *Mathematica* reasoning behind the result of the first two elements on the second row of the following table?

```
numbers = {1, 1.0}
domains = {Integers, Rationals, Reals}
TableForm[Outer[Element, numbers, domains],
 TableHeadings -> {numbers, domains}]
```

I'm not just looking for a justification; I want to know how *Mathematica* approaches this problem.

Comment: `1.` is an approximation with 15.95 digits. I.e. it could be anything in some small interval about the integer 1. The thing that is being approximated may or may not be rational/integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `Element` function does not test the Wolfram representation of the number (exact integer, floating point real, etc.), but the mathematical meaning of the number (integer, real, etc.). Compare the followings:

```
Element[1., Integers]      (* 1. ∈ Integers *)
Element[1 + 0. I, Reals]   (* 1. + 0. I ∈ Reals *)
```

These examples indicate that the numbers, represented in the Wolfram Laguage to some numerical precision, might or might not be the representations of the mathematical number `1` - as it depends on the precision.